# Keyup is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#age").keyup(function() {

    var dInput = $('#age').val().replace(/,/g, "");
    console.log(dInput);

    if (dInput > 1) {
      console.log("in");
      $(".fStep2").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $(".fStep2").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
  $("#age").blur(function() {
    var dInput = parseInt($('input:text[name=age]').val().replace(/,/g, ""));
    console.log(dInput);

    if (dInput > 1) {
      console.log("in");
      $(".fStep2").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $(".fStep2").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fStep2 {
  background-color: orange;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<input type="text" id="age" class="age" name="age">
<div class="fStep2" id="fStep2" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

I am creating a page where i have created a input type text and div. I want to div to appear only when value in textbox is more than 1. But my div is not getting showed. I have created a function. but not getting the problem.here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#age").keyup(function() {
   
          var dInput = $('#age').val().replace(/,/g, "");
        console.log(dInput);
  
  if(dInput > parseInt("1")){
         console.log("in");
   $(".fStep2").css("display","block");
  }
  else{
   $(".fStep2").css("display","none");
  }
    });
  $("#age").blur(function() {
        var dInput = parseInt($('input:text[name=age]').val().replace(/,/g, ""));
        console.log(dInput);
  
  if(dInput > parseInt("1")){
         console.log("in");
   $(".fStep2").css("display","block");
  }
  else{
   $(".fStep2").css("display","none");
  }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

 

</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <input type="text" id="age" class="age">
      <div class="fStep2" id="fStep2" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" >
        <input type="text" >
        </div>    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: when you say not working what do you mean?`$('input:text[name=age]')` you dont have input with name age

Comment: `parseInt("1")` There is no point in doing this, just put `1`

Answer (score 0):

You do not loaded jquery.js and assign name to your textbox or change the below line

```
 var dInput = parseInt($('input:text[name=age]').val().replace(/,/g, ""));
```

edit your script with the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#age").keyup(function() {
    var dInput = parseInt($('input:text[name=age]').val().replace(/,/g, ""));
    console.log(dInput);

    if(dInput > parseInt("1")){
        console.log("in");
        $(".fStep2").css("display","block");
    }
    else{
        $(".fStep2").css("display","none");
    }
});
 $("#age").blur(function() {
    var dInput = parseInt($('input:text[name=age]').val().replace(/,/g, ""));
    console.log(dInput);

    if(dInput > parseInt("1")){
        console.log("in");
        $(".fStep2").css("display","block");
    }
    else{
        $(".fStep2").css("display","none");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: @user5397448, you are still not including the core jQuery library

Comment: add this script in your page '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>'

Comment: @Nikhil.Patel When i added the script tag its working but my menu disappeared. Is there any dependency? Both the things are not working simultaneously

Comment: i think in your code you forget to add '});' in end.

Comment: @Nikhil.Patel Even after adding the }); its not working. When i added core library it worked but my menu disappeared.

Comment: Check your menu don't have class 'fStep2' because you hide it

Comment: no, I haven't put fStep2 in menu item. I am getting this error $ is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$('input:text[name=age]')
```

with

```
$("input:text[name='age']")
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your expected result, use below

```
  var dInput = $('#age').val().replace(/,/g, "");
    console.log(dInput);
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JKLyjJ

Comment: @user5397448, which works for the value greater than 1 and hides on removing input

Comment: <script src="https: //code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> ... you can copy and paste from the codepen

Comment: With this CDN it works but it is rising another problem that is its hiding my menu bar

Answer (score 0):

The only issue in your code is the missing `$(document).ready` closing brace and parentheses. "})". If you click on "run snippet", you will see script errors. I tested with your code snippet after removing all your scripts and adding jQuery from the snippet editor. So get rid of all the script elements you do not need here and insert jQuery correctly. Test with the simplest case.

Comment: I have closed the $(document). Now i am getting  $ not defined error.

Comment: @user5397448: Did you include jQuery? Add the following. <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Also remove your style.css and script.js from code. They cannot be accessed from the snippet. Also remove jquery validation and google ad services from your code. Simplify to isolate your issues.

Comment: With this CDN it works but it is rising another problem that is its hiding my menu bar

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by menu bar. I have added a code snippet to your question. Once it is peer reviewed it should come up. Go through that and then respond to what issue remains

Comment: I mean my Nav bar which represents menu items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117882/discussion-between-santon-and-user5397448).